# Best way to reverse lines in a csv file python

Tags: python, csv, reverse

I want to know the best way to reverse the lines of a big csv file (+50000 lines) in python 2.7 and rewrite it, avoiding the first line.

```
input:
A;B;C
1;2;3
4;5;6

output
A;B;C
4;5;6
1;2;3
```

I need to know how to do it in a  efficient way in python 2.7.

Thank you guys,

menchopez

Comment: @IsaacDj OP clearly said reverse except for the first line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read the csv file using `csv` module and open the output also using `csv` module. Now you're working with `list`s as rows.

Use `next` to write the title line as-is. Now that the first line is consumed, convert the rest of the data into a `list` to read it fully and apply `writerows` on the reversed list:

```
import csv

with open("in.csv") as fr, open("out.csv","wb") as fw:
    cr = csv.reader(fr,delimiter=";")
    cw = csv.writer(fw,delimiter=";")
    cw.writerow(next(cr))  # write title as-is
    cw.writerows(reversed(list(cr)))
```

`writerows` is the fastest way of doing it, because it involves no python loops.

Python 3 users have to open the output file using `open("out.csv","w",newline="")` instead.

Comment: Is `writerows` really the fastest? The cpython [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_csv.c#L1272) seems to indicate that `writerows` calls `writerow` anyways. Internally `writerows` uses a loop, so I don't see why it would be faster. Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: it's using a loop, but a C loop, not a python loop, so it's faster, as quoted in my answer _because it involves no loops at script level_

Answer (score 3):

If you can use external libraries, the pandas library is good for large files:

```
import pandas as pd

# load the csv and user row 0 as headers
df = pd.read_csv("filepath.csv", header = 0)

# reverse the data
df.iloc[::-1]
```

If you cannot use external libraries:

```
import csv

with open("filepath.csv") as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)


    # get data
    data = [row for row in reader]
    # get headers and remove from data
    headers = data.pop(0)

# reverse the data
data_reversed = data[::-1]

# append the reversed data to the list of headers
output_data = headers.append(data_reversed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read as follows:

```
rows = []
first = True
for row in reader:
    if first:
        first = False
        first_row = row
        continue
    rows.append(row)
```

write as follows:

```
rows.append(first_row)
writer.writerows(rows[::-1])
```

Comment: `writer.writerow(rows.pop)` => `writer.writerow(rows.pop())` else it doesn't work.

Comment: I would have used `writer.writerows(reversed(rows))` because it's faster than a loop.